# Is this JQuery Masonry do what it is supposedly do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I need to make a grid of images similar to this page:

http://www.clearlyinventory.com/product/screenshots/inventory-management-software-view-5

It is an image gallery or grid of images. It has pagination included, which I wonder if there is an existing plugin for that. But my real question is here:

While searching for a sample in the web, I have found this JSFiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/7ZVb7/

I also tried to do it in my own with the latest js file, but the same result appeared. I don't think either that the code snippet below is wrong.

```
$( function() {

    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 70
    });

});
```

The thing is, I think it doesnt work properly, or is it? The official website of Masonry illustrates:

[image]

My problem is that the former is still the result even after applying Masonry.

What is the problem with the jsfiddle code above (Firebug detected no erros)?

(Optional Question)Or if you know some JQuery plugin that will meet my requirements in the first place, please give me a link so that I don't have to make the pagination feature.

Comment: latter, or former. latter would be the one on the right, former the one on the left. the latter is the one that should be applied with masonry.

Comment: the javascript file you are including for masonry is returning 404 NOT FOUND, that's probably why it isn't working.

Comment: @KevinB Depends whether you're standing in front or behind the monitor :P

Comment: Oh it does work now in jsfiddle after updating the js through cdn... Thought it was updated, my dumb mistake, thanks Kevin B. My problem now is that I cant work it in my ASP.net code...

Comment: Hey fixed it. This must be some ASP.net violation. My div tag has is consists of 'runat="server"', which I almost always do since I call ajax content in every div controls. It worked fine after removing it.